# Using sonarlint-cli for C++ analysis

Tags: sonarlint

I hoped to use sonarlint-cli (2.0) for pre-commit analysis of C++ with a remote SonarQube server (5.6.1), but when updating the binding and downloading analysis plugins, it tells me the cxx plugin (among others) is not compatible:

```
DEBUG: Plugin cxx is not compatible with SonarLint. Skip it.
```

This is the community C++ plugin (0.9.6).

I'm wondering about the compatibility rules for plugins with SonarLint, and about alternative pre-commit approaches.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SonarLint web site](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/#Connected), the connected mode "will make SonarLint use the analyzers, quality profiles and settings defined on your SonarQube server." However, that is not entirely true.

SonarLint does not support the non-sonarqube analyzers. Thus, it does not support PMD, checkstyle, FindBugs, C++ community plugin, and others. So, even if these analyzers are defined on your SonarQube server and quality profiles, they will **not** be used.

You may ask why. In a [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/_sNZF-xYnyc), it's said that SonarLint can only work perfectly and superfast if these other analyzers do not run.

I personally think that statement is detrimental to the developers of these other tools. The decision not to support third-party plugins is also problematic to organizations (like mine) that have invested a lot of time in polyglot static code analysis. Remember, for 5+ years many people have created custom checks and custom rules using checkstyle and PMD, for example. Back then, sonar (ergo sonarqube) did not offer an API for Java custom checks.

I'm worried that SonarQube might eventually drop support for all these external plugins altogether.